# How to get s:radio with label content as empty

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, radio-button, ognl

I am using the struts tag `s:radio` as below;

```
<s:radio list="radioOptions" name="answer%{#ques.pageNbr}%{#ques.seqNbr}" value="defaultAnswer" />
```

That is generating the HTML output as below;

```
<input type="radio" name="answer11" id="answer11Yes" value="Yes"/><label for="answer11Yes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="answer11" id="answer11No" value="No"/><label for="answer11No">No</label>
```

However I don't want the label content like **Yes** or **No**.  I am loading an image instead of that.  How can I make that label content as blank or `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a map to populate a [radio](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/radio.html) tag. The value of the map is used as a label, the key is used as a value.

```
<s:radio name="answer%{#ques.pageNbr}%{#ques.seqNbr}" list="#@java.util.HashMap@{'Yes':'','No':''}" />
```